# how to get Emacs org-mode to play sound file on DONE state?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, audio, aquamacs

I'd like org-mode to reward me for completing a task by playing a nice sound when I change the state of a `TODO` item to `DONE`.

I tried two variations in my `.emacs` file, neither one worked. I'm on Aquamacs on OSX.

Neither of these worked:

```
'(org-after-todo-state-change-hook (quote (org-clock-out-if-current) (play-sound-file "~/Library/Sounds/InkSoundStroke3.aif")))

'(org-after-todo-state-change-hook (quote (org-clock-out-if-current)     (start-process-shell-command "afplay" nil "mplayer ~/Library/Sounds/InkSoundStroke3.aif")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: if you check the docstring for the hook (<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `org-after-todo-state-change-hook` <kbd>RET</kbd>) you'll see that the new state is available in the variable `org-state`, so we can test for that:

```el
(add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook 'my-org-after-todo-state-change)
(defun my-org-after-todo-state-change ()
  (when (string-equal org-state "DONE")
    (org-clock-out-if-current)
    (play-sound-file "~/Library/Sounds/InkSoundStroke3.aif")))
```

Comment: Thanks. I get `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument symbolp (quote my-org-after-todo))
  (defun (quote my-org-after-todo) nil (play-sound-file "~/Library/Sounds/InkSoundStroke3.aif"))
  eval-buffer()  ; Reading at buffer position 32470
  call-interactively(eval-buffer nil nil)`

Comment: Apologies, there was a rogue quote in there. Try it now.

Comment: Clearly that is the correct solution to my original question, thank you! I'm now getting `This Emacs binary lacks sound support`, but I think that's a different problem.

Comment: Update: I fixed the "lacks sound support" problem using this package: https://github.com/leoliu/play-sound-osx at it works now.

Comment: The above plays a sound whenever a `TODO` state is changed. Is it possible to play it only when it hits `DONE`?

Comment: `OSX` alternative:  ... `(require 'org-clock)`; `(shell-command (concat "afplay /path/to/tada.mp3"))`; `(kill-buffer "*Shell Command Output*")`; `(message "Congratulations!")`.

Comment: Personally I have several `DONE` states, therefore, for the condition I do the more general `(member todo-state org-done-keywords)`

Comment: Also I'd like to add that `play-sound-file` is a blocking function, i.e. you have to wait until the sound ends before being able to do anything else. To get something non-blocking, I would use async shell commands, e.g. `(start-process-shell-command "org-done-sounds" nil
       (format "aplay %s" "~/Library/Sounds/InkSoundStroke3.aif"))`